# Join 3 tables with duplicate values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have 3 tables

Subject table where I store subjects and its details

```
subject_id
subject_code
title
lec_units
lab_units
year_offered
course_offered
sem_offered
```

Enrolled table where I store student enrolled subjects

```
id
course_code
student_id
subject_code
year_enrolled
school_year
```

And lastly, Grades table where I store the student grade per subject

```
grade_id
student_id
subject_code
grade
```

I select the grades for printing like this:

```
Select g.subject_code,g.grade,su.title,su.year_offered,su.sem_offered,e.school_year from grades g left join subjects su on g.subject_code= su.subject_code left join enrolled e on g.subject_code = e.subject_code where (g.student_id='" + data_listview.FocusedItem.Text + "' and su.sem_offered = '1st' and e.year_enrolled= '1st')
```

But since in my enrolled table, another student is also enrolled to the same subject, I get duplicate rows. So how can I prevent having duplicate rows? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT
  g.subject_code,
  g.grade,
  su.title,
  su.year_offered,
  su.sem_offered,
  e.school_year
FROM grades g
LEFT JOIN subjects su
  ON g.subject_code = su.subject_code
LEFT JOIN enrolled e
  ON g.subject_code = e.subject_code

  and g.student_id = e.student_id  -- you are missing this to link the student

WHERE (g.student_id = '" + data_listview.FocusedItem.Text + "'
AND su.sem_offered = '1st'
AND e.year_enrolled = '1st')
```

Comment: Hi, so I tried adding distinct as you first commented, and it worked, tried doing this, also worked, I prefer this solution better. Thanks you saved my life!

Comment: this is the appropriate solution and not the distinct cheers.